# how to create ajax grid then bind data to its column using foreach loop?

Tags: c#, ajax, gridview, model-view-controller, viewmodel

this is the view strongly typed with

```
@using HRHPMVS.ViewModel
@using HRHPMVS.Models
@model IEnumerable< HRHPMVS.ViewModel.NationalityVM>
```

view model NationalityVM:

```
public class NationalityVM
{
    public Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
```

this is the model:

```
public class Nationality
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Requirde")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "please: Use letters only ")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Code")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Code is Requirde")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+", ErrorMessage = "{0} must be a Number.")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please: enter valid integer Number")]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public Nullable<short> IsActive { get; set; }
```

this is my repository function:

```
public List <NationalityVM> list()
{
    List<NationalityVM> l1 = new List<NationalityVM>();
    SqlDataReader DR ;

    DR = Ado.ExecDataReaderProc("NationalitiesSelectAll");

    while (DR.Read())
    {
        NationalityVM vm = new NationalityVM();
        vm.Nationality = new Nationality
        {
            Code = Convert.ToInt32(DR["Code"]),
            IsActive = Convert.ToInt16(DR["IsActive"]),
            Name = Convert.ToString(DR["Name"]),
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(DR["ID"])
        };

        l1.Add(vm);

    }

    return l1;
```

this is my controllet :

```
public ActionResult list()
{
    List<NationalityVM> model = NationRepObj.list();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View(model);
}
```

and this is my grid view :

```
<div id="gridContent" style="padding-right: 40%;">
    @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "webGrid",
        fillEmptyRows: false,
        alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
        headerStyle: "grid-header",
        footerStyle: "foot-grid",
        mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
        firstText: "<< First",
        previousText: " < Previous",
        nextText: "Next >",
        lastText: "Last >>",
        caption: "Nationalties Details",
        emptyRowCellValue: null,
        columns:
        grid.Columns(
            grid.Column("ID", format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode">@Model.GetEnumerator()</span>
                <label id="ID" class="edit-mode"></label>
                </text>),
            grid.Column("Name", "Name", format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode">
                <label id="lblName">@item.Name</label>
                </span>
                <input type="text" id="Name" value="" class="edit-mode" />
                </text>),
            grid.Column("Code", "Last Name", format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode">
                <label id="lblCode"></label>
                </span>
                <input type="text" id="Code" value="" class="edit-mode" /></text>),
            grid.Column("IsActive", "IsActive", format: @<text>
                <span class="display-mode">
                <label id="lblIsActive"></label>
                </span>
                <input type="text" id="IsActive" value="" class="edit-mode" />
                </text>),
            grid.Column("Action", format: @<text>
                <button class="edit-user display-mode">  Edit</button>
                <button class="delete-user display-mode"> Delete</button>
                <button class="save-user edit-mode">  Save</button>
                <button class="cancel-user edit-mode"> Cancel</button>
                </text>, canSort: false)
        )
    )
</div>
```

my model does not contain any item i have to loop frist using foreach like:

```
@if( Model !=null)
{
    foreach ( var item in Model)
    {
        @item.Nationality.Code
        @item.Nationality.ID
        @item.Nationality.Name
        @item.Nationality.IsActive
```

how can i do the loop in the grid in order to display items??

Comment: What do you mean by `ajax grid`?  I don't see any ajax here.

Comment: um trying to implment this code https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1411/editable-webgrid-in-asp-dot-net-mvc

Comment: in my code but i have to loop through item in model first to display the fields

Comment: you should bind your model to the grid, not loop over your model.  Look at the first example here:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/843788/WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC-important-tips

Comment: i want to make it inline editable and my not strongly type to  model strongly type to viewmodel

Comment: obje.colum only appear when i use foreach